# Stored Procedure doesn't return correct ROWS

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a Stored Procedure to filter user input data. Currently, there are two parameters.

`Status` which is `bit` and can be `0` or `1` and `OrgUnitId` which is an `int` and can be between `0` and `9`.

Right now, whatever I create `OrgUnitId` doesn't return value which I sent.

```
DECLARE 
@Status bit = 0,
@OrgJed int = 5
BEGIN
IF(@Status = 0) 
BEGIN
 SELECT PrezimeIme,NetworkLogin,Status,OrgUnitId,DT_Creat,DT_Modif
  FROM  tblZaposleni_AD 
  WHERE Status = @Status
 END

 ELSE IF(@Status = 1) 
 SELECT PrezimeIme,NetworkLogin,Status,OrgUnitId,DT_Creat,DT_Modif
  FROM  tblZaposleni_AD 
  WHERE Status = @Status

END


IF(@OrgJed = 0)
BEGIN
    SELECT PrezimeIme,NetworkLogin,Status,OrgUnitId,DT_Creat,DT_Modif
      FROM  tblZaposleni_AD 
      WHERE OrgUnitID = @OrgJed


    IF(@OrgJed = 1)
    SELECT PrezimeIme,NetworkLogin,Status,OrgUnitId,DT_Creat,DT_Modif
      FROM  tblZaposleni_AD 
      WHERE OrgUnitID = @OrgJed


     IF(@OrgJed = 2)
    SELECT PrezimeIme,NetworkLogin,Status,OrgUnitId,DT_Creat,DT_Modif
      FROM  tblZaposleni_AD 
      WHERE OrgUnitID = @OrgJed

    IF(@OrgJed = 3)
    SELECT PrezimeIme,NetworkLogin,Status,OrgUnitId,DT_Creat,DT_Modif
      FROM  tblZaposleni_AD 
      WHERE OrgUnitID = @OrgJed


    IF(@OrgJed = 4)
    SELECT PrezimeIme,NetworkLogin,Status,OrgUnitId,DT_Creat,DT_Modif
      FROM  tblZaposleni_AD 
      WHERE OrgUnitID = @OrgJed

    IF(@OrgJed = 5)
    SELECT PrezimeIme,NetworkLogin,Status,OrgUnitId,DT_Creat,DT_Modif
      FROM  tblZaposleni_AD 
      WHERE OrgUnitID = @OrgJed

    IF(@OrgJed = 6)
    SELECT PrezimeIme,NetworkLogin,Status,OrgUnitId,DT_Creat,DT_Modif
      FROM  tblZaposleni_AD 
      WHERE OrgUnitID = @OrgJed

    IF(@OrgJed = 7)
    SELECT PrezimeIme,NetworkLogin,Status,OrgUnitId,DT_Creat,DT_Modif
      FROM  tblZaposleni_AD 
      WHERE OrgUnitID = @OrgJed

    IF(@OrgJed = 8)
    SELECT PrezimeIme,NetworkLogin,Status,OrgUnitId,DT_Creat,DT_Modif
      FROM  tblZaposleni_AD 
      WHERE OrgUnitID = @OrgJed

   IF(@OrgJed = 9)
    SELECT PrezimeIme,NetworkLogin,Status,OrgUnitId,DT_Creat,DT_Modif
      FROM  tblZaposleni_AD 
      WHERE OrgUnitID = @OrgJed
END
```

I tried to create `SELECT` statement and It return `12 rows`

```
SELECT *
FROM [DesignSaoOsig1].[dbo].[tblZaposleni_AD]
WHERE Status = 0 AND OrgUnitID = 5
```

But when I run the stored procedure I get 163 rows, and I see that `OrgUnitId` is not the value which I sent. I suppose the problem is in `IF` statement, but whatever I change I get always same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not clear what your filter criteria is, but a single query should do the job e.g.

```
DECLARE
    @Status bit = 0, -- Could be null
    @OrgJed int = 5  -- Could be null
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON; 

    SELECT *
    FROM [DesignSaoOsig1].[dbo].[tblZaposleni_AD]
    WHERE (@Status IS NULL OR [Status] = @Status)
    AND (@OrgJed IS NULL OR OrgUnitID = @OrgJed)
    -- I assume at least one parameter has to be non null
    AND (@Status IS NOT NULL OR @OrgJed IS NOT NULL);

    RETURN 0;
END
```